# Mupdate sql query return an error: limit 1

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

```
<?php

// find current order

       $current_order_id = find_order_by_id($_GET['order']);
       if(!$current_order_id){
         redirect_to("orders.php");
       }
?>

<?php
      $id = $current_order_id["id"];
      $menu_name = $_POST["menu_name"];
      $address = $_POST["address"];
      $contact = $_POST["contact"];
      $transaction = $_POST["transaction"];
      $flemingia = $_POST["flemingia"];
      $goat_manual = $_POST["goat_manual"];
      $lbc_tracking_no = $_POST["lbc_tracking_no"];
      $visible = $_POST["visible"];


      $query  = "UPDATE orders SET ";
      $query .= "menu_name = '{$menu_name}', ";
      $query .= "address = '{$address}', ";
      $query .= "contact = {$contact}, ";
      $query .= "transaction = '{$transaction}', ";
      $query .= "flemingia = {$flemingia}, ";
      $query .= "goat_manual = {$goat_manual}, ";
      $query .= "lbc_tracking_no = {$lbc_tracking_no}, ";
      $query .= "visible = {$visible} ";
      $query .= "WHERE id = {$id} ";
      $query .= "LIMIT 1";
      $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
      if($result){
        die("Database connection failed. " . mysqli_error($connection));
      }
?>
```

**and this is the error I got:**
Database connection failed:*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 1*

can someone explain why this is happen

i suspect that i pickup wrong `id` so i `echo` my `query` and i got! a right `id`

**output of my query:**

`UPDATE orders SET menu_name = '', address = '', contact = , transaction = '', flemingia = , goat_manual = , lbc_tracking_no = , visible = WHERE id = 20 LIMIT 1`

**note:** *`contact`, `flemingia`, `goat_manual`, `lbc_tracking_no`, `visible` are all `INT`*

**===============================Update===================================**

**My Form**

`<h1>Create Order : <?php echo $current_order_id["menu_name"]; ?></h1>
  <p class="error"><?php echo $message; ?></p>
<form action="edit_order.php" method="post">
  <p><span>Name</span>:
    <input type="text" name="menu_name" value="<?php echo $current_order_id["menu_name"]; ?>" />
  </p>
  <p><span>Address</span>:
    <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $current_order_id["address"]; ?>" />
  </p>
  <p><span>Contact Number</span>:
    <input type="text" name="contact" value="<?php echo $current_order_id["contact"]; ?>" />
  </p>
  <p><span>Transaction</span>:
    <input type="text" name="transaction" value="<?php echo $current_order_id["transaction"]; ?>" />
  </p>
  <p><span>Flemingia</span>:
    <input type="text" name="flemingia" value="<?php echo $current_order_id["flemingia"]; ?>" />
  </p>
  <p><span>Goat Manual</span>:
    <input type="text" name="goat_manual" value="<?php echo $current_order_id["goat_manual"]; ?>" />
  </p>
  <p><span>LBC Tracking NO.</span>:
    <input type="text" name="lbc_tracking_no" value="<?php echo $current_order_id["lbc_tracking_no"]; ?>" />
  </p>
  <p><span>visible</span>:
    <input type="radio" name="visible" value="0" <?php if($current_order_id["visible"] == 0){echo "checked";} ?> />No
    <input type="radio" name="visible" value="1" <?php if($current_order_id["visible"] == 1){echo "checked";}?> />Yes
  </p>
  <input class="submit_btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit Order" />
</form>`

**this is all my function**

```
<?php
     function redirect_to($new_location){
       header("Location:" . $new_location);
       exit;
     }
     function confirm_query($result_set){
       if(!$result_set){
      die("Database connection failed. ");
    }
    }

    function find_all_order(){
      global $connection;

      $query  = "SELECT * ";
      $query .= "FROM orders";
      $order_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
      confirm_query($order_set);
      return  $order_set;
    }
    function find_order_by_id($order_id){
      global $connection;

      $query  = "SELECT * ";
      $query .= "FROM orders ";
      $query .= "WHERE id = {$order_id} ";
      $query .= "LIMIT 1";
      $orderset = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
      if(!$orderset){
        die("Database connection failed:" . mysqli_error($connection));
      }
      if($order = mysqli_fetch_assoc($orderset)){
      return $order;
      }else{
        return null;
      }
    }


?>
```

Comment: See those empty values? Bingo.

Comment: Must be `$query .= "visible = '{$visible}' ";`

Comment: @JohnConde is that necessary to have e `value` even i dint hit the `submit` button

Comment: Seems to start at `$query .= "contact = {$contact}, ";` where it should read as `$query .= "contact = '{$contact}', ";` etc.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Make it an answer , I hope this is not a _Can of worms one_ :P

Comment: `contact` is an 'INT` that's why i don't put single quote(`'`)

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Done. Now, we sit and wait ;-)

Comment: Let's see your form then @jhunlio also make sure your column sizes are big enough to accomodate the lengths. Plus, you are connected to DB, right?

Comment: Plus, this `if($result){` should be `if(!$result){` @jhunlio

Comment: thank's for your time @Fred-ii- i appreciate it so much by the way yes i'm connected to my DB and all in 'CRUD' is working fine except `UPDATE`

Comment: You're welcome. See my **Edit** in my answer below. @jhunlio there are two options to try.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Looks like my solution worked along with the comments given to find OP a solution :-) It took a while, but glad it worked out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I know where the problem is. You need to use the [`multi_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php) function.

Try this:

```
if(!$connection->multi_query($query)){ 
echo "Multi query failed: (" . $connection->errno . ") " . $connection->error;
}
```

instead of `$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);`

---

### Edit

Try this method then:

```
 $query  = "UPDATE orders SET menu_name = '$menu_name', address = '$address', 
 contact = $contact, transaction = '$transaction', flemingia = $flemingia, 
 goat_manual = $goat_manual, lbc_tracking_no = $lbc_tracking_no, visible = $visible 
  WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
  
  if(!$result){
    die("Database connection failed. " . mysqli_error($connection));
  }
  
  else{
  echo "Success";
  }
```

or:

```
 $query  = "UPDATE orders SET menu_name = '".$menu_name."', address = '".$address."', 
 contact = $contact, transaction = '".$transaction."', flemingia = $flemingia, 
 goat_manual = $goat_manual, lbc_tracking_no = $lbc_tracking_no, visible = $visible 
  WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
  
  if(!$result){
    die("Database connection failed. " . mysqli_error($connection));
  }
  
  else{
  echo "Success";
  }
```

However, if some of your entries contain hyphens, that could be a factor.

---

#### Original answer

You have quotes missing for some of your variables:

`{$flemingia}` - `{$goat_manual}` - `{$lbc_tracking_no}` - `{$visible}`

```
  $query  = "UPDATE orders SET ";
  $query .= "menu_name = '{$menu_name}', ";
  $query .= "address = '{$address}', ";
  $query .= "contact = {$contact}, ";
  $query .= "transaction = '{$transaction}', ";
  $query .= "flemingia = '{$flemingia}', ";
  $query .= "goat_manual = '{$goat_manual}', ";
  $query .= "lbc_tracking_no = '{$lbc_tracking_no}', ";
  $query .= "visible = '{$visible}' ";
  $query .= "WHERE id = {$id} ";
  $query .= "LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

Edit: deleted `{$contact}` from the list, since OP said it is an `int`

However, you may need to put them back in, since this `contact = ,` is part of your error message, along with the others.

Your `{$id}` did not have any and it shows up correctly in your echo'ed query.

Comment: thank's for the time it return this error: Database connection failed. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' transaction = '', flemingia = , goat_manual = , lbc_tracking_no = , visible = ' at line 1

Comment: You're welcome @jhunlio I'm curious about this function `find_order_by_id()` is there anything being echo'ed in your form with `value="<?php echo $current_order_id["menu_name"]; ?>"`? Where is that function located and what's in it?

Comment: I think I know where the problem is. You need to use `multi_query()` try this `if(!$connection->multi_query($query))echo "Multi query failed: (" . $connection->errno . ") " . $connection->error;}` 
instead of `$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);` @jhunlio

Comment: I placed it on top of my answer in an edit. @jhunlio Crossing my fingers.

Comment: i post all of my function in my update @Fred -ii- also i change `$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);` to this `if(!$connection->multi_query($query)) echo "Multi query failed: 
(" . $connection->errno . ") " . $connection->error;}` it return this error:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\exercises\exercise3\public\edit_order.php on line 32, I think that because of close bracket(`}`)

Comment: My mistake I forgot a `{` I edited my answer with `if(!$connection->multi_query($query)){ echo "Multi query failed: (" . $connection->errno . ") " . $connection->error;}` @jhunlio

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51313/discussion-between-jhunlio-and-fred-ii)

Comment: **Update:** I created a DB with what I had to work with, yet not using your `find_order_by_id()` function, and then used `WHERE id = '$id'` instead of without quotes and it worked. I was getting the same errors when using without quotes `WHERE id = $id` @jhunlio Plus, using `$query .= "WHERE id = '{$order_id}' ";` instead of `$query .= "WHERE id = {$order_id} ";` in the functions file. Otherwise, I would get an error.

Comment: Plus, I did not use `multi_query()` but left your code pretty much intact, besides putting `$current_order_id = find_order_by_id($_GET['order']);` and DB connection include file inside the form itself instead of inside the functions file. @jhunlio